# Trig calculations through estimation

Tags: trigonometry

How would you go about calculating $\cos(\frac{8}{e\pi})?$ I know the answer is 0.9998663385 using a calculator, but is there a way to estimate this answer? Is there an identity I can use?

Comment: That's nowhere near $\cos(8/e\pi)$.

Comment: According to THE GOOGLE, the answer should be around 0.59.  This, of course, assumes that the angle is measured in radians.  If $\frac{8}{\mathrm{e} \pi}$ is measured in degrees, you get your answer...  So the first thing to do is make sure that you have the correct units.

Comment: Sorry, I did it again and got 0.592371358592.

Comment: It's true, *if* you interpret $\frac8{\pi e}$ as an angle in degrees. In radian, that's $\frac8{180e}$, so it's no wonder the $\cos$ is that close to $1$.

Comment: How close do you want "to estimate this answer"? What would you do with the estimate since you already have a calculator value? I would really like to know.

Comment: I'm a high school teacher and one of my student's is teaching himself higher level math, so he's trying to figure out how he would solve this without using a calculator.

Answer (score 1):

Let $u={\pi\over3}-{8\over e\pi}\approx0.11$.  Then we can use a trig identity and Taylor series for

$$\begin{align}
\cos\left(8\over e\pi\right)
&=\cos\left({\pi\over3}-u\right)=\cos\left(\pi\over3\right)\cos u+\sin\left(\pi\over3\right)\sin u\\
&={1\over2}\left(1-{1\over2}u^2+\cdots \right)+{\sqrt3\over2}\left(u-{1\over6}u^3+\cdots\right)\\
&\approx{1\over2}+{\sqrt3\over2}u\\
&\approx0.595
\end{align}$$

If you need a better approximation, you can use more digits of $u$ and more terms of the Taylor series for $\cos u$ and $\sin u$.

Comment: Thank you, that is just what I was looking for.